# Вызов метода из дочернего под-класса

Tags: java

Есть структура

```
public interface CacheService {
    void getId();
}

public class AbstractDaoService implements CacheService {
    public void getId(){}
}

public interface UserDaoService {}

public class UserDaoServiceImpl extends AbstractDaoService implements UserDaoService {}

public class MyOtherClass {}
public class MyClass extends MyOtherClass {
    UserDaoService userService=new UserDaoService();

    myMethod(){
    userService.super.getId(); // Можно ли как-то это реализовать?
}
```

У меня собственно вопрос, можно ли как-то это реализовать кроме как добавление вот так?

```
public class UserDaoServiceImpl extends AbstractDaoService implements UserDaoService {
    public myOtherMethod(){
    super.getId(){}
    }
}

public class MyClass extends MyOtherClass {
    UserDaoService userService=new UserDaoService();

    myMethod(){
    userService.myOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

Почему бы не имплеметировать `CacheService` сразу в UserDaoServiceImpl, потому что другие классы тоже, в будущем, должны будут использовать метод из `CacheService`. И в каждый класс добавлять интерфейс, мне кажется, не красиво )

Comment: зачем называть `public class AbstractDaoService` его абстрактным если он не Абстрактный. Вы можете если так взять, создать его объект и использовать.

Comment: а вызвать `userService.super.getId();` так нельзя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать Reflection Api

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

interface CacheService {
    void getId();
}

class AbstractDaoService implements CacheService {
    @Override
    public void getId() {
        System.out.println("Привет: AbstractDaoService::getId()");
    }
}

class UserDaoServiceImpl extends AbstractDaoService {
}

public class TestDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
        UserDaoServiceImpl service = new UserDaoServiceImpl();

        Class<UserDaoServiceImpl> sClass = UserDaoServiceImpl.class;
        Method method = sClass.getSuperclass().getMethod("getId");
        method.invoke(service);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Привет: AbstractDaoService::getId()
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что я переопределяю метод интерфейса в абстрактном классе. Либо мне надо сделать это где-то так, чтобы туда могли "посдоединиться" еще около 20 классов, чтобы реализовать переопределенный метод, а точнее просто его выполнить, подставив свои данные. Структура такая `Interface->Abstract Dao class-> Dao class -> Мой класс` который должен вызывать метод из интерфейса

Comment: @Dred 1. `public class AbstractDaoService` это не абстрактный класс, абстрактный класс записывается так: `public abstract class AbstractDaoService`.
2.  А почему бы не создать, новый класс, который будет расширять ваш базовый абстрактный класс? И реализовать в нем, нужный метод?

Comment: можно и так. это не проблема, как к нему обратиться из 3 поколения? xD
Нашел, что есть применение `Class cl=myClass.getSuperClass();` Но чего-то не получается вытащить из него мои методы

Comment: @Dred посмотрите, обновил ответ. Можно использовать `reflection api`

Comment: а как передать параметры в getId() если понадобится? P.S. Странно, ваше имя удаляется, если поставить `@`

Comment: @Dred обновил код, так что бы можно было достучатся до метода супер-класса, что бы передать параметры, используйте метод `invoke` через него.

Comment: Спасибо. Не уверен, что будет пременен этот метод решения, но как вариант, очень удачно.